# Downloading and XPathing crossdomain document

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I'm asking you for solution of problem described in the title.
I found lot of possible solutions, but there also lot of problems.

**What I want to do?**
I want write a function `foo(nick)` which returns extracted information from `other.com`.

**How I want to do it?**
 1. I want to download content of `other.com`.
 2. Then i want to parse it as HTML.
 3. Next I want to extract (with xpath) some useful information's

Yours sincerely
Aliron

Answer (score 0):

If the browser supports CORS and the server has [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) enabled than you can make an Ajax call.

When the browser or server do not support it, you need to use a serverside proxy on your domain to fetch the content.

Comment: It is no answet to my question. i know i can use something to do something and blablabal

Comment: I answered your original question which you proceeded to change. Just remember I am trying to help you out for free so stop being so rude.